# How to use Imagick to merge and mask images?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I know very little of image processing and even less of the terminology used, so please bear with me.

Basically, I want to merge two images together where one of them will act as a mask. That image looks something like this:
[image: Example]
Where the blue and yellow background are both transparent in reality.

This image is being used as a mask for regular photo's. Parts of the photo that 'stick out' of the circle need to be 'cropped' (be made invisible) while the inside remains visible.
So everything that comes in the blue area is invisible, everything in the yellow area is visible.

I honestly have no clue how to go about it so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
I use the API version of Imagick, not the commandline version

**Edit:**
To get a feel of what I want to achieve, here is an example.

The input images are thus:
[image]
This is the mask image, always the same

[image]
This is an example of a picture, dynamic

[image]
This is what the end result should look like

Comment: I really need an answer for this question. My knowledge is too limited to research it myself so that's why i'm starting a bounty. If the question needs to be improved i will gladly do that.

Comment: would the command line version help..?

Comment: If it can't be done with the API, I would have to resort to the CLI, but I've got a strong favor towards the API version.

Comment: Do you want that black border to show on the final image?

Comment: @DennisHaarbrink Sorry my solution assumed your overlay was always a black circle. It doesn't work for colored images. I'll try to find something else.

Comment: @Cicada: It's a good start. When an image contains little or no white it works like a charm, otherwise it breaks down bad.. real bad.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

So, finally, this should do what you need:

> **Original image:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7seR.png]

> **Opacity mask:**

[image]

> **Overlay:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ulkM.png]

> **Output:**

[image]

The code:

```
<?php
$base = new Imagick('U0R4F.png');
$mask = new Imagick('mask.png');
$over = new Imagick('3ulkM.png');

// Setting same size for all images
$base->resizeImage(274, 275, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

// Copy opacity mask
$base->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);

// Add overlay
$base->compositeImage($over, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);

$base->writeImage('output.png');
header("Content-Type: image/png");

echo $base;
?>
```

I hope it's right now!
Note: In your example it looks like you downscaled the base image, which I didn't (my goal is just to show how the masking is done).

Comment: This looks promising! I will create a mask image and test this code.

Comment: Yeah I guess some scaling should occur. I'm gonna test the new code now.

Comment: Great, this is almost perfect! One problem, any transparancy in the original image is converted to black. Is there a way to preserve the alpha channel?

Comment: Thanks so much! This does exactly what is needed. All I need is proper scaling, but I think I can manage that by myself. You deserve the bonus!

Comment: I had to make one little tweak though, add a check whether an image has an alpha channel use a different composition method: `if ($base->getImageMatte()) {
 $base->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
} else {
 $base->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
}`

Comment: Please excuse my insistance, but if you do not manually award the reputation bonus to one of these answers before the end of the bounty, then half of it will be lost. Cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry, haven't been able to award the bounty and was under the impression that it would get awarded automatically to the selected answer.

Comment: I also had to change the lines a little bit to

$base->compositeImage($mask, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0, \Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
$base->compositeImage($over, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0, \Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);

BUT, I cannot get rid of the black background where my mask and overlay are both transparent.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly This is exactly what I want to do, but how do I do it using command line instead of PHP? And batch process it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this solution here as described by : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2351173/1093649 ?

Run this in your server (with the right image names!), and let us know, thanks.

nb : credits go to [jspash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263566/jspash)

Comment: I had already found that one, but it doesn't really do what I want. The net effect of that answer is that the blue and yellow parts in the image stay transparent while the black border displays the 'background' image.

Comment: Too bad, can you attach the original images to your post? That way, we can get a better idea to where you are starting from.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample input and output images.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#dstin should do the trick, but you need to use images with alpha channels (that shouldn't be a problem).

Edit: in PHP you have to pass it (`imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN`) as a parameter in [compositeimage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-compositeimage.php). Other filters in [Composite Operator Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.constants.php) may also be useful to you.

Comment: This doesn't really help. Of course I've found the compose function, but I just don't know how to combine the tools available to create the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

This type of masking is exampled using a number of different techniques in
ImageMagick Examples, Thumbnails, Mask and Paint
   http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#mask_paint

Be warned however that the masking and the edges of the overlay image SHOULD NOT MATCH
this is important or you may get problems with edge aliasing effects that is best avoided.

Extracting an alpha mask of the ring, can be done using morphology operators to thin it down to a centerline can be used to generate a mask for any random 'ring' shape.
ImageMagick Examples, Skeletons by Thinning, and Pruning
  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#thinning_skeleton

Anthony Thyssen
Web Master for ImageMagick Examples, and Developer for ImageMagick

PS: nice photo from Elfling