# MiniMagick: How do I add an overlay stock image that's larger than the source?

Tags: ruby, image-processing, minimagick

We're trying to achieve building a custom social sharing image from our app. The backend is built using Ruby/Sinatra and we already use MiniMagick+AWS-SDK to upload user images.

What we want to do is take the user's image and add a stock overlay (it contains a white circle as the placeholder for the variable user image) on top of the user image. I tried using MiniMagick's built-in `composite` method using `Over` as the operator, but the problem with `Over`is, if the overlay is larger than the source, it automatically adjusts according to the source's size. Our overlay is larger and we **want to retain** the overlay such that the resulting image has the complete overlay with the part of the user image that fits the placeholder white circle visible underneath.

I tried [How to use Imagick to merge and mask images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699228/how-to-use-imagick-to-merge-and-mask-images) but it doesn't solve my problem.

Basically, say this is the overlay.

[image: Stock Overlay]

And take this sample user image as example:

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/71/08/b5/7108b5a89ce3d6cc0341f876681f8546.jpg

I would like the resulting image to be the complete overlay with the user image visible behind one of those while circles.

**Update**

As per [Mark's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell)answer, I wrote the following Ruby code to achieve the result:

```
avatar = avatar.resize "200x200"
result = mask.composite(avatar) do |c|
    c.compose "DstOver"
    c.geometry "+100+120" #this could be different depending on your mask's dimensions
end
```

You can test the result by executing `result.write "result.jpg"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure what you are doing as your mask is an opaque JPEG? However, I think you mean to use a transparent PNG for the mask with a hole in it, in which case you could do this:

```
convert mask.png \( avatar.jpg -resize 200x200 \) -geometry +360+150 -compose dst-over -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Could you confirm mask.png is the background image and avatar.jpg the cartoon's link I provided?

Comment: No, they are not, you provided an opaque JPEG for the mask which nothing will show through - so I made a PNG out of it with a transparent hole in it.

Comment: Ah, okay. Also, could you please walk me through how this solution achieves the result and how do I translate this to Ruby code?

Comment: Sorry I don't speak Ruby. I basically take the avatar and resize that to 200x200. Then I take the mask and the resized avatar, move the avatar over to the right place with `-geometry` and then use a `Dst-Over` composition to composite the mask over the avatar.